# Can I have multiple onClickListeners for the same expandableListView?

Tags: android, onclick, expandablelistview

I have an `onClickListener` sucessfully set up for my custom `ExpandableListView`

```
elv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, 
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    }
);
```

Can I have a `onGroupClickListener` somewhere in the same class too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I have multiple onClickListeners for the same expandableListView?

Short answer: No.

You could:

1. Have the one child click listener do many things.
2. Design your own custom listener system for registering custom listeners.  Register custom listeners in your custom listener system.  Have the one child click listener of the ExpandableListView tell the custom listener system to iterate through all of its listeners and notify them of the event.

> Can I have a onGroupClickListener somewhere in the same class too?

Yes.  You could create and register one very much like you did for the child click listener.

Comment: ok, well I need to know when a group item is clicked and I need to know when a child item is clicked. Is it possible to put them in one general `onClickListener`?

Comment: Updated my answer to cover both of the original questions.  If you register both listeners, then they'll get called according to what I understand you're trying to achieve: when a group item is clicked, the group click listener will be notified; and when a child item is clicked, the child click listener will be notified.